What are the criteria for a subject to be under the domain of mathematics
It is to my understanding that mathematics is in some way the domain of all logical systems. However unconventional, as long as certain criterias are met, they could be considered as part of mathematics. For example, subjects like ring theory or knot theory are quite far fetched from the "normal" number oriented math, but since it is logical, it is...considered math?
The criteria I can think of could include self-consistency? This also relates me into thinking about Godel's incompleteness theorem, but I dont have enough knowledge to put into words how that would affect the question I am asking.
Can I say that any system that is "logical", whatever that means (which I hope someone could put into better words) would then be under the domain of math?
There is also an element of computation that is related but again, I lack the proper knowledge and vernacular.
I am editing to add a third question, that is how computation and statistics, which I believe originated from mathematics, has now detached itself from math and became its own subject? I think the fairly obvious answer for computation is that it involves a lot of non theoretical elements that is entirely based on real world application, which of course there is overlap between the two subjects, similar to statistics.
And obviously there is an element of subjectivity in all the questions here but roughly speaking, what direction should I look to find the blurry line that distinguishes a subject from math, or include itself in math?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'm always amused when people say things like 'subjects like ring theory... are quite far fetched from the "normal" number oriented math'. Few subjects in modern mathematics are closer to being "about numbers" than ring theory!

It reminds me of George Bergman's bemused response in this old YouTube gem: https://youtu.be/SB3Ekgt1pHw?t=2m14s
